# Chat FAQ update request - Include instructions on moving messages

Tags: support, chat, faq-update-request, meta-faq

As far as I have seen from my reading of the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq), none of the sections tell room owners how they can move messages to another room, like the *bin* room. After being added as an owner to the Android room, it took me more than two weeks to figure out how to move messages, and that was after asking one of the other owners who'd been around longer.

Basically, I'm asking if this information could be added to the FAQ, perhaps under a new "What can room owners do?" section, which can also contain information on how they can control access, schedule events etc.

How to move messages:

You *must* be an owner to do this.

1. Click on the room drop down in the sidebar and select `message admin`
2. Your mouse will become a cross hair when hovering over messages in the room. Select single messages with one click, or multiple messages with shift-click and/or control-click (doesn't work on a Mac)
3. Once selected, click the relocate button in the dialog that would have popped up after #1. Then simple enter the name of the room you want to move the message to, and select it from the search results that appear (you'll have to press enter)